# Qt Cannot open include file: 'QNetworkAccessManager': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, include, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm new to Qt, and I keep running into weird errors. Here is one of them: I have a class named NetworkHandner that includes QNetworkAccessManager (`#include <QNetworkAccessManager>`). I added `QT += network` in my .pro file. Everything works great. However, when I try to include my NetworkHandler class in mainwindow.h (`#include "networkhandler.h"`), I get the error in the title. I am really confused, as everything compiles and works great until I include the networkhandler header inside another header. Can anyone point me in the right direction? How can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Rerun qmake after changing anything in your project file.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really works! I don't know how I've missed this details before. I've been trying for a few hours to build my project. Thank you once again!

Comment: No worries, also don't forget to rerun `qmake` if you change build type (Debug/Release/Profile) after your project file was modified.

Answer (score 0):

`QNetworkAccessManager` comes with the QtNetwork module. You could do this: `#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>`, which should compile. However, it will not link, you need to link to QtNetwork. To achieve this, you should tell QMake that you're using QtNetwork. Add this to your `.pro` project file: `QT += network`.

This has two effects: first, the compiler will look for include files in the QtNetwork subdirectory too (so you don't need to include `<QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>`, `<QNetworkAccessManager>` will work just fine). Secondly, the linker will link to QtNetwork too. So everything will work just fine.